# list_to_float error

Tags: erlang

I understand that `list_to_float("123")` gives a badarg error but why `list_to_float(["12.34"])` gives also the same error ?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
list_to_float("12.34")
```

`list_to_float` accepts a `String` and it returns a float whose text representation is the `String`.

Comment: It's a list of strings with one element "12.34"

Comment: I thought that a string was considered as a list ? In my example, how can I evict the error ?

Comment: A string is a non-deep list with only integers which represents characters. In your example ["12.34"] is really [[49,50,46,51,52]] which is a deep list. Some functions (like io:format) can handle deep-lists, but most then the documentation will say that it does.

Comment: Yes, a string is a list of **integers**. Your argument is a list of list of integers. It is one level too deep.